# USB hub errors on boot

Tags: boot, usb

Whenever I boot up my pi, before the login screen arrives, I get an error like the following (listed intermittently among other boot loggings):

```
hub 1-1:1.0: cannot disable port 3 (err=-110)
```

over and over again, and a keyboard attached to the USB ports doesn't work. I am running arch linux on my pi. What could I do to fix this?

EDIT: this refers to the internal USB hub.
EDIT: this still happens with nothing in the USB ports.

Comment: I would suggest this is power issue. Can you describe the rest of your setup?

Comment: I power the raspberry pi and a  portable projector by a computer, and the raspberry pi is plugged into the portable projector and the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a powered USB hub?

Sometimes the Raspberry Pi cannot deliver enough power to the USB hub in order for it to work.

EDIT: This has been solved by a user on the Raspberry Pi forum:

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=6608&p=84647

By upgrading to a better quality power supply, enough power was reaching the USB ports to stop this issue. You might also want to consider using an external powered USB port to supplement any extra devices you're plugging in.

EDIT 2: DO NOT power your Raspberry Pi off a usb socket on your computer :D

Comment: It's the internal USB hub.

Comment: Do you mean the two USB ports actually on the device?

have you attempted to remove the keyboard and check if it boots okay without it, or inserted another USB device to see if it is just the keyboard that is causing the issue?

Comment: Exactly. And this comment is now long enough.

Comment: Check the previous comment, I've edited it.

Comment: It still gives me errors when there is nothing in the USB port.

Comment: A similar post on Raspberry Pi's forum has solved this issue: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=6608&p=84647

Apparently, they upgraded their power supply to a much better quality one. What type of power supply are you currently using?

Comment: I'm currently plugged into a computer.

Comment: Do not power it off of a computer USB port - it does not provide enough voltage / amps (I can't remember which one).

Comment: Use something similar to a mobile phone charger, I'd recommend this one from Adafruit: https://www.adafruit.com/products/501/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I realize the only time I had it working I was plugged into a TV's USB port, which probably ignores the .7A limit. I ordered a Wall-to-2A5V USB online.